# Can I specify the expected host key fingerprint for Ansible ssh?

Tags: ssh, ansible

I'd like to be able to check the public key fingerprint for each host (the ssh servers) in an inventory into my `host_vars` directory. All my searches on the topic lead me to various resources describing either how to specify the client key or how to disable host key checking altogether. It seems to me though that once I've established that a host (server) key is authentic, it would be good to share that knowledge with others and keep the security benefit of host key checking. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you already aware of [`SSHFP` DNS records](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4255)? There's a [Unix stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60027/configuring-ssh-fingerprints-on-dns-to-replace-known-hosts-fails) posting about the nuts and bolts, too

Comment: I wasn't aware of them and they look useful so thanks for the comment!

Comment: Btw, if the person who downvoted the question could let me know what they objected to, I can take their point of view into consideration when posting in future. Thanks.

Comment: It's likely related to the one close vote your question has, where the voter felt this material belonged on superuser.com; `ansible` has always been this weird hybrid of stackoverflow and superuser, same with `kubernetes`, pragmatically

Comment: Thanks @MatthewLDaniel, that's certainly something I should consider whether or not that was what the downvoter was thinking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect that in the same way those articles you have read are updating [`ansible_ssh_common_args`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/plugins/connection/ssh.html) in order to set  `-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null` you can similarly update that fact to use `-o UserKnownHostsFile={{ playbook_dir }}/my_known_hosts` to bundle the known hosts file alongside the playbooks that would use them

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks like it would really do the trick for me but I'd like to test it out before marking it as the answer. Please bear with me as it might take a little while for me to find the time for this.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to test your very helpful answer. I have finally confirmed that it works so thank again for your help.